# In an Event-Driven Microservice, how to I update private database with older data

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I'm working on a new project, and I am still learning about how to use Microservice/Domain Driven Design.

If the recommended architecture is to have a Database-Per-Service, and use Events to achieve eventual consistency, how does the service's database get initialized with all the data that it needs?

If the events indicating an update to the database occurred before the new service/db was ever designed, do I need to start with a copy of the previous database?

Or should I publish a 'New Service On The Block' event, and allow all the other services to vomit back everything back to me again? Which could be a LOT of chatty-ness, and cause performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does the service's database get initialized with all the data that it needs?

It asks for it; which is to say that you design a protocol so that the service that is spinning up can get copies of all of the information that it needs.  That often includes tracking checkpoints, and queries that allow you to ask what has happened since some checkpoint.

Think "pull", rather than "push".

Part of the point of "services": designing the right data boundaries.  The need to copy a lot of data between services often indicates that the service boundaries need to be reconsidered.

Comment: Thank you! Good points. My thoughts of "alot of data" was more historical. Even a few records per day, over a few years, could be a sizable amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special streaming platform named Apache Kafka, that solves something similar.
With Kafka you would publish events for other services to consume. What makes Kafka special is the fact, that events *never* (depends on configuration) get deleted and can be consumed again by new services spinning up. This feature can be used for initially populating the database (by setting the offset for a Topic to `0` and therefore re-read the history of events).

There also is another feature, called `GlobalKTable` what is a TableView of all events for a particular Topic. The `GlobalKTable` holds the latest value for each key (like primary key) *and* can be turned into an state-store (RocksDB under the hood), what makes it queryable. This state-store initializes itself whenever the application starts up. So the application does not need to have a database itself, because the state-store would be kept up-to-date automatically (consistency still is a thing to keep in mind). Only for more complex queries that state-store would need to be accompanied with a database (with kafka you would try to pre-compute the results of those queries and make them accessible to a distinct state-store itself).

This would be a complex endeavor, but if it suits your needs it is a fun thing to do!

Comment: Thank you! I'm accepting the answer provided by @VoiceOfUnreason because it answered the question at a higher, more abstract level. Your suggestion of Kafka is an excellent implementation too. If I could accept both, I would.